# Sync dropbox file for android

Tags: java, android, file, api, dropbox

I was wondering why my file is not updating to dropbox. Currently it only creates the an empty file.

```
final String TEST_FILE_NAME = DateTime + ".txt";
        DbxPath path = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, TEST_FILE_NAME);
        try {
            if (!FileSystem.exists(path)) {
                newFile = FileSystem.create(path);
                try {
                    newFile.writeString("Hello world!");

                } finally {
                    newFile.update();
                    newFile.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (DbxException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `update` before `close`? I wonder if that's destroying the data you just wrote. Also, it would be good to include in your question whether `writeString` is actually succeeding or not.

Comment: Hmm, I added update as a check, but even without the update it does not write. However, when I call newFile.readString(), the string reads. So I am thinking it has something to do with updating the file.

Comment: So when you say the file isn't being updated in Dropbox, you mean that you don't see the contents when you look on the web? Or maybe on the desktop? (It seems that in code, you *do* see the right contents.)

Comment: When I say it isnt being updated, I mean when I check my file on my dropbox. Also, on the right side of the screen it should say, "File ___ has been updated to its latest," however it doesnt.

Comment: By "on my Dropbox" do you mean the website? Or a client (desktop, mobile, etc.)? And what does happen? A zero-byte file appears?

Comment: I have checked on my desktop, the website, and the app, all with the same results. It creates a file that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I never unlinked my dbxacc and kept relinking, causing errors to show up! Silly mistake.